# Error: Unable to open Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I am getting an error when I click on Eclipse Marketplace

> Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
>   Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Connection failed
>
> This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
>
> Cannot complete request to marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Unable to connect to repository 
>   Unable to connect to repository 
>   Connection to marketplace.eclipse.org refused
>   Connection failed

help me

Comment: This is obviously obvious, but: are you connected to the internet?

Comment: So obvious... Do you even have an internet connection?

Comment: Ummm--by definition, a question on stackoverflow came from someone connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy HTTP settings (should you need one), as it could be incorrect. Please review eclipse documentation on how to adjust the Eclipse-internal proxy settings ... if that is where the problem lies.

In order to quickly check if this issue is limited to eclipse and not related to general internet connectivity issue, try connecting to that URL with a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing RelevantKnowledge software from your machine. Mine is Windows 10. Issue is not appearing after removal of RelevantKnowlege software.